# How do I select element by class name added after document is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to target an element by a class name that I've added to it in jQuery.  This seems to work fine if I add a new element, but I can't get the new events to bind to an element that was already in the DOM, but has been changed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$(".activateRow").on("click",function(){
     $(this).text('Deactivate').addClass('deactivateRow btn-danger').removeClass('activateRow btn-success');
     $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('inactiveRow');
 });

$(".deactivateRow").on("click",function(){
    $(this).text('Activate').removeClass('deactivateRow btn-danger').addClass('activateRow btn-success');
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('inactiveRow');
});

 })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To bind to new elements use delegation :

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".deactivateRow", function(){
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will accept as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems a little messy, I suggest you use the data api, your elements can have attributes set with data-nameOfYourAttribute='Value'. You can use this in jquery like this:
    //This is a getter/setter
    $('#myElement').data('nameOfYoutAttribute')

And for your problem you can do:

```
$('.myRows').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).data('activated') == false) {
       //Do stuff
       $(this).data('activated', true);
    } else {
       //Do stuff
       $(this).data('activated', false);
    };
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Just doing some view testing.  Final code will be much cleaner.  Thanks for the suggestion.